# Laravel log different user out

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

On my website administrators are granted permission to generate a new password for users and email them their new password.

How can I also end all sessions for the user who now has a new password?

I am using laravels `Auth` class.

For a users to log themselves out I use `Auth::logout();`

Comment: You could take a look at the source code of laravel: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php

Comment: Judging by the code and docs, you should call `Auth::setUser($user)` before calling `logout()` and pass it an `User` instance. However, I just tried it and it does not work - it logs _me_ out, not the user that I passed to it. Maybe it's a bug... In any case, I submitted an [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8448) so you might want to follow that

Comment: It's not a bug, @KaloyanDoichinov. setUser makes your log as if you where the $user in the variable. Useful if you want to test as if you where that user. The logout() method logs out the one calling the method. So its all working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

For returning visitors, if you're using Eloquent and have set your database up using their guides, then your user table should have a `remember_token` field. Deleting the contents of this field will prevent them from being automaticall logged in next visit.

However, in the short term, Laravel knows if a user is logged in by their session id. I don't believe there is a way around this in pure Laravel, however you could probably add it, by extending the Auth class. You could then force it to check the database for a value you've set to see if a user needs to be forced out.

How exactly you do this in Laravel, I'm not sure. Theoretically the Facade's should make this easier, but in my experience the opposite is true. If this question is still open on Monday when I get back to work, I'll see if I can work it out for you, but I'm not Laravel's biggest fan and refuse to use it at home. ;p